# How do I compare data from VB ListView and data from MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listview

What I want to do is that i want to compare the `String` value from `ListView` which is the `list.SubItems(2).Text` and see if the product already exist. If it does then it should just update the Quantity, otherwise it should be added as a new product. It works fine when there's only one item on the `ListView` however, if the theres two (or more) an error occurs saying `"Reader is closed..."`, if I remove `reader.Close()` I will get the error saying `"There's already an open reader..."` PLEASE HELP!

```
    Dim iLoop As Integer
    Do Until iLoop = lvwSI.Items.Count
       list = lvwSI.Items.Item(iLoop)
       command.CommandText = "SELECT Product_Name FROM tblProduct "
       command.Connection = connect
       reader = command.ExecuteReader()
       While reader.Read()
          If list.SubItems(2).Text = reader.GetString(0) Then
             reader.Close()
             command.CommandText = "UPDATE tblProduct SET Quantity = '" & list.SubItems(0).Text & "' WHERE Product_Name = '" & list.SubItems(2).Text & "'"
             command.ExecuteNonQuery()
             'WHAT TO DO?!?!
          End If
       End While
       reader.Close()
       command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblProduct(Product_Name,  Quantity, Unit, Description) VALUES ('" & list.SubItems(2).Text & "', '" & list.SubItems(0).Text & "', '" & list.SubItems(1).Text & "','" & list.SubItems(3).Text & "')"
       command.ExecuteNonQuery()
       iLoop = iLoop + 1
       list = Nothing
 Loop
```

Comment: Well, for starters you close `reader` while you're still reading from it.  Then you try to close it again after the `While` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in your code is not doing what you expect it to do.

First, you're closing your `reader` once you find a match.  If there are rows remaining, you will get an error trying to read from `reader` on the next loop, because you closed the reader.

Secondly, you're always going to be inserting the product because you don't set a flag to indicate whether the product was found in the While loop.

Third, you're reading the same set of data multiple times (for every item in the `ListView`).  That's expensive and unnecessary.

Fourth, I woudl expect quantity to be an int in your table, and you're trying to store a string, which could be a problem (maybe not in MySQL).  To be safe (if the column really is an int) I'd convert the string to an int before sending to the database.

A better approach would be to read the list of products from the table one time and store them in a `List<String>`, and then loop through the list of items in the `ListView`. If you find a match, you update the quantity.  If you don't find a match, you insert the product.

```
Dim productNames As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
command.CommandText = "SELECT Product_Name FROM tblPRoduct"
command.Connection = connect

Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While (reader.Read())
        productNames.Add(reader.GetStrign(0))
    End While
End Using

For iLoop As Integer = 0 To lvwSI.Items.Count - 1

    list = lvwSI.Items.Item(iLoop)

    If productNames.Contains(list.SubItems(2).Text) Then
        command.CommandText = "UPDATE tblProduct SET Quantity = " & CInt(list.SubItems(0).Text) & " WHERE Product_Name = '" & prodName & "'"
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Else
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblProduct(Product_Name, Quantity, Unit, Description) VALUES ('" & list.SubItems(2).Text & "', " & CInt(list.SubItems(0).Text) & ", '" & list.SubItems(1).Text & "', '" & list.SubItems(3).Text & "')"
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If 
Next
```

**EDITED TO ADD**

If you want to add the quantity in the `ListView` for the item to the quantity in the database, simply do it in the SET statement:

```
SET Quantity = Quantity + " & CInt(list.SubItems(0).Text)
```

So the full command would look like this:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE tblProduct SET Quantity = Quantity + " & CInt(list.SubItems(0).Text) & " WHERE Product_Name = '" & prodName & "'"
```

Comment: I tried using your code but I'm having this error: `Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()`.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I added a `While` loop inside the `Using` block to actually *read* the reader.

Comment: Can I ask one more thing? :D I want to add the value of _Quantity_ in the `ListView` to the value of _Quantity_ in the database. How do I do this? :D

Answer (score 0):

For me Using Reader is a bit risky because when two client computers Query from the server at the same time, it may cause one of the two client computer to Query no data "Connection is close"

i use this Function to secure all my client computers without closing the Database.

```
Public Function getSingleTestParameterData(ByVal sQuery As String) As String
    getSingleTestParameterData = Nothing
    Try
        Dim dataS As DataSet
        connectToDB()
        CMD = New SqlCommand(sQuery, TestResult)
        sqlAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(CMD)
        dataS = New DataSet
        sqlAdapter.Fill(dataS, "getSingleData")
        getSingleTestParameterData = dataS.Tables("getSingleData").Rows(0).ItemArray(0).ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Function
```